# is there a way to change multiple tags at once?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I decided to change a tag which is commonly used.  Is there an easy way to change it for all my content or do I have to manually go in and change each one?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed the tag itself from taxonomy. It will change for all content that use the tag. The only issue you may run into is if your doing url paths based on any taxonomy terms.