# Tagging of multiple content items at once

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm very new to Drupal, so please be gentle.

My company is in the process of setting up Drupal as a learning portal, which will have various content types (videos, pdfs, blogs, basic pages) that we will tag for ease of searching and offer 'suggested learning materials'.

While we will try to get our taxonomy defined perfectly up front, we know we'll miss something.

I came across two related questions here, but neither are exactly what I am asking

- [Add a field to multiple content types at once?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46110/add-a-field-to-multiple-content-types-at-once)
- [is there a way to change multiple tags at once?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38930/is-there-a-way-to-change-multiple-tags-at-once)

I'll certainly use these questions and answers in the future, but for now my question is:

if we add a new term (rather than change one), is there a way to select multiple content items and add the new terms to the selection in a single action, rather than have to go to each content item individually and add the new tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and customize a [vbo](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) view, which would allow you select multiple content items and add a taxonomy term to all the selected items at once.

Jason

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've heard reference to VBO, but so far I've not done anything with it/them. However, now I have a reason. As such, I'm marking your reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) on the terms.

Then implement [hook_entity_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7), drop the data from the entity reference so it doesn't get saved, and instead used it to load up the referenced entities, tag them, and save them back.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Jasons answer (above) seems to me, the complete novice, the easier to understand given that I've heard of VBO (in reference only), though I do need to review hooks at some stage. For that reason, I'm marking his as the answer, though yours will prove useful too, I'm sure.